# Get coordinates of geogson feature in Mapbox

Tags: java, android, mapbox, geojson, mapbox-android

A GeoJson feature looks like this :

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      43.59375,
      59.17592824927136
    ]
  }
}
```

In `Mapbox` using Java/JVM we can construct the feature like this :

```
val testFeature = Feature.fromGeometry(Point.fromLngLat(2.0,3.0))
```

But I don't seem to find a method to get coordinates/point back from the feature.

There is a `Feature#getGeometry()` but I can't get the coordinates from that either as that's just a sugar for the GeoJson interface itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just found that Each Feature expose the method `.geometry()` which we can cast to any type **(Point, Line, polygon, Multipoit.. etc)**. From there we can get the **either** `Point` **or** `List<Point>`.

Example :

```
val position1 = feature1.geometry() as Point
val longitude = position1.longitude()

val area1 = feature2.geometry() as MultiPoint
val firstPointLatitude = area1.coordinates()!![0].latitude()
```

Comment: Looks like this throws an error <java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mapbox.geojson.Polygon cannot be cast to com.mapbox.geojson.MultiPoint>

Answer (score 1):

Each feature has a `.coordinates()` method that returns a `List<Point>` or `List<List<Point>` object (unless you're calling it on a `Point` feature, in which case it will return a `List<Double>`.

[source: [core API's geojson documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/api/mapbox-java/libjava-geojson/4.3.0/com/mapbox/geojson/Point.html#coordinates--)]

Comment: [Feature.class](https://docs.mapbox.com/archive/android/java/api/libjava-geojson/4.3.0/com/mapbox/geojson/Feature.html) doesn't have a `.coordinates()` method though — you'd have to call `feature.geometry()` and then cast to a specific feature type first